# after-init-hook vs eval-after-load/with-eval-after-load

Tags: init-file, package

I've found the rather useful [How Packages work in Emacs 24](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc4), however, I'd like a definitive answer from an experienced user or a core developer as to which of these is actually preferred in the typical case on 24.4.

Afaik, `(add-hook 'after-init-hook ...)` is the so-to-say brute-force approach to setting up customizations for packages. However, `eval-after-load` and its more syntactically sugary `with-eval-after-load` seem more appropriate for more dynamic and fine grained configuration that plays well with the gradual, separate and lazy loading of extensions.

Is my understand correct? What else should I keep in mind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Afaik, `(add-hook 'after-init-hook ...)` is the so-to-say brute-force approach to setting up customizations for packages.

No. If you want to configure packages in your init file, the typical
approach is to call `(package-initialize)` at the top of the file, and
then do the configurations. `after-init-hook` is unnecessarily
complicated for this purpose.

> However, `eval-after-load` and its more syntactically sugary `with-eval-after-load` seem more appropriate for more dynamic and fine grained configuration that plays well with the gradual, separate and lazy loading of extensions.

`(with-)eval-after-load` is used for things you want to do *after* a
package is loaded. `package-initialize` doesn't load the packages, it
only “prepares” them (loads their autoloads).

If you use `eval-after-load` around every set of configurations, you
won't need to call `(package-initialize)` at the top. But what people
usually do is to call `(package-initialize)`, so that most
configurations can be written straight to the init file, and then only
`eval-after-load` code which is very long or which depends on the
package being loaded.

Comment: but it would still be OK to put everything under `eval-after-load` for any given package, right, and not use `(package-initialize)` at all?

Comment: @ErikAllik Yes. If you use eval-after-load around every set of configurations, you won't need to call (package-initialize) at the top.