# When should I use with-eval-after-load in my configuration files?

Tags: init-file, package, window

I went over my configuration files and wanted to do some cleanup.

My understanding of `with-eval-after-load` was that its body would be evaluated right after the related package is loaded. While cleaning up my configurations files and splitting them even more, I wanted to enclose every package configuration with `with-eval-after-load`. Everything went as expected until I enclosed the configuration for `helm` and `helm-projectile`.

Here is what I had in mind ([lisp/init-helm.el](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/ae2eba9abd6e6abb826e49198b5b2a21661ed904/lisp/init-helm.el#cl-19)):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'helm
  (setq helm-mode-line-string "")
  (add-to-list 'helm-sources-using-default-as-input 'helm-source-man-pages)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-c m") 'helm-imenu)
  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-x b") 'helm-buffers-list))

(with-eval-after-load 'helm-command
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x))

(with-eval-after-load 'helm-projectile
  (helm-projectile-on))
```

After restarting Emacs, I get this window size issue:

[image: emacs-window-size-issue]

This is how I resize my window:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullboth)
```

I'm guessing I am misusing `with-eval-after-load`, how would one sanitize his Emacs configuration and make sure nothing breaks no matter what package are installed ?

Comment: This is utterly bizarre. (Possibly a bug?)

Comment: Do you have any idea what this could be related to? I'm using railwaycat's OS X port and I don't want to add an issue where this doesn't belong :).

Comment: I tried to use `with-eval-after-load` to wrap all of my package-related customizations once. Then I [saw the light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TSKxxYEbII) and started using [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) instead.

Comment: @itsjeyd This looks very handy and convenient indeed ! I ran into some trouble however: I commented out `(package-initialize)` and replaced it with `(require 'use-package)` but I will get *File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, use-package* when restarting Emacs. And yet, once Emacs has started I can eval `(require 'use-package)` with no issue. Finally, I even tried `with-eval-after-load`, still same error. The readme isn't very clear on how to *install* `use-package` when using packages from package.el.

Comment: Show us your `.emacs`, preferably a stripped-down version that demonstrates the problem with as few lines and as few external packages as possible. This probably has to do with timing of frame setup vs package load during [startup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html). But without seeing your code, there's not much we can do. Also tell us which version of Emacs you're using.

Comment: @Gilles I actually put a link to [my dot files](https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src/ae2eba9abd6e6abb826e49198b5b2a21661ed904/lisp/init-helm.el#cl-19) in the post. Since then I started to use `use-package` as @itsjeyd advised, and I can't replicate the issue. I noticed that when I was wrapping `helm-command` and `helm-projectile`, Emacs would start up instantly (as in so fast that it's like it didn't load any package).

Comment: @MathieuMarques [This](https://github.com/lunaryorn/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L42) is a nice config I used as a guide on how to use use-package.

Comment: The answer to your original question is here:  
http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3624/9895  
(but I like what I see of `use-package` too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with `helm` initialization (or little).

In my everlasting quest to optimize Emacs' start-up time, I have moved all of *interface* related things at the very beginning of my configuration. That includes the pseudo fullscreen that I use.

Putting the corresponding line before any of the heavy lisp was loaded fixed my issue.

[Here is my configuration for reference](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org).

Comment: repo link is deleted

Comment: @alper Hello :-) Sorry, I moved it to Github some years ago now. Here is the link https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/dotemacs.org I don't use Helm anymore though.

Answer (score 2):

I use `with-eval-after-load` a lot, mostly for adding or removing elements to or from lists after the default values have been evaluated. That way I don't have to keep track of changes in the default values.

As for the problem with your `helm` initialization, [the documentation](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#quick-install-from-git) recommends that `(require 'helm-config)` be present in your `init.el` or its dependencies.

I've found that it's easier just to require `helm-config` during initialization rather than relying on `autoload`, especially since I would be loading it almost immediately most of the time anyway.

Comment: I've changed since then to use `use-package`, and even while requiring `helm-config` I still get the same issue. Here is my updated config setup: https://bitbucket.org/angrybacon/dotemacs/src.